# Creating a new window over a window in another module using toplevel in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, module, toplevel

I would like to create a window over a window in another module using top-level method.

Is there a way to separate my GUI into modules if I didn't use the object oriented approach?

Here is a simple example, first module (`file1.py`):

```py
import tkinter
from file2 import user

global MainWindow
MainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
MainWindow.geometry("320x300")
MainWindow.title("")

def check():   
    user()

button1 = tkinter.Button(MainWindow,width = '15'
                         ,text="check", bg="green", fg="orange"
                         ,command = check)
button1.place(x=20,y=20)

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

and the other module is (`file2.py`) :

```py
from tkinter import *
from file1 import MainWindow

def user():
    userWindow = Toplevel(MainWindow)
    userWindow.geometry("320x300")
    userWindow.title("hello")

    user_name = Label(userWindow, text = "hello")
    user_name.place(x = 20, y = 190)
```

but in this case it's not possible. I wonder why it is not possible and whether
there is a solution I am looking for.

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? What is it doing when you run the code?

Comment: i tried it. it didn't run, the error message is " cannot import name 'user' from 'file2'"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention why you think it's not possible, though I'm guessing it's because `user` doesn't know what `MainWindow` is. That, and you have a circular import.

The simple solution to that is to pass it in as a parameter, and *not* have `file2.py` try to import `file1.py`.

```
# file1.py
...
def check():   
    user(MainWindow)
...
```

---

```
# file2.py
def user(MainWindow):
    ...
```